# How to validate inserted items in AJAX Combobox against database?

Tags: asp.net, validation, combobox

I wonder how to validate if a inserted item in a Combobox exists in a database during postback? If the item.text exists, a errormessage should notify the user that the item already exists in the database. If the item does not exists in the database a inserting should be done.

Should i use the customvalidator and create a servervalidationfunction that searches my databasetable for the item name?

Should i validate inside one of the two ComboBox control events, ItemInserting and ItemInserted?

After validating the existence i would like to validate if the inserting to the database was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

So you're going to hit your database to check whether an item already exists and then if it doesn't, deem the item valid, and then hit your database again to insert the new item? I suggest you simply try to insert the item via say a stored procedure and have the stored procedure check whether the item already exists in your table. Your stored procedure can then return a result which your web application can digest (i.e. whether the item already existed versus successful/failed insertion). This way you only hit the database once.